Custom timestamp in ksqldb stream with Avro in Schema Registry
I'm using Schema Registry, Avro, and KSQLDB. I am creating a stream, but I would like to use a custom timestamp for event-time, not the insert time. ksqldb docs
I have hard-coded the VALUE_SCHEMA_ID to the pre-loaded schema (in this case of ID 1).
Avro schema:
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Price",
  "namespace": "dh762",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "node_id",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "timestamp",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}

ksql statement:
CREATE STREAM stream_1 (
    node_id VARCHAR KEY
) WITH (
    KAFKA_TOPIC='prices',
    VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO',
    PARTITIONS=3,
    VALUE_SCHEMA_ID=1,
    TIMESTAMP='timestamp',
    TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SSSX'
);

The error I get:
io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlStatementException: 
The TIMESTAMP column set in the WITH clause does not exist in the schema: 'TIMESTAMP'

Full stacktrace:
2024-05-08 11:22:59 [2024-05-08 09:22:59,648] ERROR Failed to start KSQL (io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain:104)
2024-05-08 11:22:59 io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlStatementException: The TIMESTAMP column set in the WITH clause does not exist in the schema: 'TIMESTAMP'
2024-05-08 11:22:59     at io.confluent.ksql.engine.EngineExecutor.plan(EngineExecutor.java:688)
2024-05-08 11:22:59     at io.confluent.ksql.engine.SandboxedExecutionContext.plan(SandboxedExecutionContext.java:159)
2024-05-08 11:22:59     at io.confluent.ksql.engine.SandboxedExecutionContext.execute(SandboxedExecutionContext.java:195)
2024-05-08 11:22:59     at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.StandaloneExecutor$StatementExecutor.handleExecutableDdl(StandaloneExecutor.java:360)
2024-05-08 11:22:59     at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.StandaloneExecutor$StatementExecutor$1.handle(StandaloneExecutor.java:392)
2024-05-08 11:22:59     at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.StandaloneExecutor$StatementExecutor.execute(StandaloneExecutor.java:321)
2024-05-08 11:22:59     at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.StandaloneExecutor.executeStatements(StandaloneExecutor.java:226)
2024-05-08 11:22:59     at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.StandaloneExecutor.validateStatements(StandaloneExecutor.java:210)
2024-05-08 11:22:59     at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.StandaloneExecutor.processesQueryFile(StandaloneExecutor.java:188)
2024-05-08 11:22:59     at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.StandaloneExecutor.startAsync(StandaloneExecutor.java:130)
2024-05-08 11:22:59     at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain.runExecutable(KsqlServerMain.java:160)
2024-05-08 11:22:59     at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain.tryStartApp(KsqlServerMain.java:123)
2024-05-08 11:22:59     at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain.main(KsqlServerMain.java:102)
2024-05-08 11:22:59 Caused by: io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlException: The TIMESTAMP column set in the WITH clause does not exist in the schema: 'TIMESTAMP'
2024-05-08 11:22:59     at io.confluent.ksql.execution.streams.timestamp.TimestampExtractionPolicyFactory.lambda$create$0(TimestampExtractionPolicyFactory.java:60)
2024-05-08 11:22:59     at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:408)
2024-05-08 11:22:59     at io.confluent.ksql.execution.streams.timestamp.TimestampExtractionPolicyFactory.create(TimestampExtractionPolicyFactory.java:58)
2024-05-08 11:22:59     at io.confluent.ksql.execution.streams.timestamp.TimestampExtractionPolicyFactory.validateTimestampColumn(TimestampExtractionPolicyFactory.java:42)
2024-05-08 11:22:59     at io.confluent.ksql.ddl.commands.CreateSourceFactory.buildTimestampColumn(CreateSourceFactory.java:313)
2024-05-08 11:22:59     at io.confluent.ksql.ddl.commands.CreateSourceFactory.createStreamCommand(CreateSourceFactory.java:121)
2024-05-08 11:22:59     at io.confluent.ksql.ddl.commands.CommandFactories.handleCreateStream(CommandFactories.java:134)
2024-05-08 11:22:59     at io.confluent.ksql.util.HandlerMaps$BuilderR2.lambda$castHandler2$2(HandlerMaps.java:840)
2024-05-08 11:22:59     at io.confluent.ksql.ddl.commands.CommandFactories.create(CommandFactories.java:112)
2024-05-08 11:22:59     at io.confluent.ksql.engine.EngineContext.createDdlCommand(EngineContext.java:233)
2024-05-08 11:22:59     at io.confluent.ksql.engine.EngineExecutor.plan(EngineExecutor.java:634)
2024-05-08 11:22:59     ... 12 more

How can I have a custom timestamp on a Avro Schema that is registered in the Schema Registry?
My versions:
confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.6.1
confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.6.1
confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server:7.6.1

edit: if I'd add the timestamp to the parameters of the stream:
CREATE STREAM stream_1 (
    node_id VARCHAR KEY,
    timestamp VARCHAR
) WITH (...)

I get
io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlStatementException: 
Table elements and VALUE_SCHEMA_ID cannot both exist for create statement.


Try TIMESTAMP='TIMESTAMP', instead, ksqlDB transforms implied field names to uppercase in many cases.

same error, it could be that linking a stream or table to an existing schema via VALUE_SCHEMA_ID is incompatible with custom timestamps, not sure yet though!

Did you ever manage to find a workaround or a cause for this error? I'm facing the exact same issue and I would very much prefer to just use Schema inference by ID + my custom timestamp...

I've resorted for now to have ksqldb create the schema and not use VALUE_SCHEMA_ID @filpa
